# What is [...] in Python Language

Tags: python, list, pycharm

So I have created a suffix tree using python and when I was printing my suffix tree, I came across one list that contains `[...]` at one of its indexes. I searched online and couldn't find anything regarding it. It would be really great if someone could explain to me that what does `[...]` mean in python. By the way, I'm using PyCharm IDE, not sure if it's an IDE specific issue. Cheers!